# Returning array from promise is undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a function that calls the iTunes API, and I return an array of objects from that. My main function calls this (and other promises) and waits for all promises to complete. This works, however, for the iTunes API promise the array returned is always "undefined".

My promise:

```
function getiTunesMusic() {
  var options = {
    uri: "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=62820413&entity=song&limit=10",
    json: true
  }

  retrieve(options) // This does a GET request
    .then(repos => {
        var result = repos.results
        result.shift() // I get the array of results, minus the first result
        console.log(result) // This prints out the full array of song objects
        return result
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        return null
    })
}
```

My code waiting for the promises completion block:

```
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(objects => {
    var music = objects[0]
    console.log("music", objects[0]) // This prints out "music undefined"
    profile.music = music
  }
```

The weird thing is when I print out the iTunes api result that I'm returning in the promise, it prints fine. However, in the promise completion block it's always undefined. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the promise from the function, hence, the default return **undefined** is returned

Try

```
return retrieve(options) // this returns the promise
```

in place of

```
retrieve(options)
```

Comment: This worked thanks! I'll accept this in a few minutes when it allows me to

Comment: Good to hear that :)